# When does the Euler characteristic from Poincare-Hopf for a Complex Vector Field equal the Euler Characteristic from Gauss-Bonnet?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis

The Poincare-Hopf theorem for a manifold with boundary states that the sum of the indices of zeros of a complex vector field $v$ equals the Euler characteristic of the manifold M if we impose 'outward' orientation along the boundary:
$$
\Sigma \text{ind}(v)  = \chi(M).
$$
On the other hand, the Gauss-Bonnet theorem says that the gaussian curvature area integral + the geodesic curvature boundary line integral $= 2\pi\chi(M)$.

Now, consider a 2D manifold X with parameters $(x,y)$, with known Euler character $\chi(X)$. Over X, I can define various complex vector fields $v1, v2, v3, ...$ (all dependent on $(x,y)$). Does $\Sigma_j \text{ind}(v_j)$ always equal  $\chi(X)$? Or are the Euler characteristics here $=\chi(M_{v1}),\chi(M_{v1}),\chi(M_{v1})...$ where $M_{vi}$ are some other manifold of each $v_i$.

My confusion is coming from a physics problem, where I have to choose a closed loop in  $(x,y)$-space, and the definition of $v_i$ depends on the choice of loop. I am trying to understand whether the index of the zeros of these $v_i$ relate at all to $= \chi(X)$.

Comment: First, you're missing a $2\pi$ in your Gauss-Bonnet. Second, what do you mean by complex vector fields? You specify parameters $(x,y)$ but you don't say they are isothermal parameters; so what do you mean by complex? And how are you defining global vector fields? Are they only defined on a topological disk (e.g., a contractible coordinate chart)? In that case, you're now recovering the topology of $X$ at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin By complex, I meant complex-valued. So, if $(x,y)$ is a plane, I choose a loop on it (which defines the manifold for $v_i$) and I can plug each $(x,y)$ point along the loop to function $v(x,y)$, which will give a complex number at each point, and so a loop on the complex plane. By the argument principle, this gives the zeros (with multiplicity) within the complex loop, and so the index of the zero in my question, which by Poincare-Hopf, gives the Euler character. But I am confused how this relates to the Euler character of the ‘plane’. Did you mean 'not' in your last sentence?

Comment: Yes, "now" should have been "not"; sorry. A vector field is a section of the tangent bundle of the surface; so you're working in a coordinate chart in which you've trivialized the bundle. I don't see the point of bringing in the complex numbers; you have no complex analytic structure here. $\Bbb C$ is for these purposes the same as $\Bbb R^2$. Anyhow, my remark stands. You have to glue all these local pieces together in a coherent way to get information about the original compact surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the insight. In my physics problem, I know that the only zero of a map $f(x,y)$ over boundary-less space X occurs at $(x_0,y_0)$, and has a Brouwer degree $n$ (which ~ $\frac{1}{2} \chi(X)$). I separately have the afore-mentioned map $v(x,y)$. If the $(x,y)$ loop I choose has $h(x,y)'s$ zero $(x_0,y_0)$ inside it, then the winding number $W$ of the complex winding loop $v(x,y)$ somehow equals $\chi(X)=2n$ (otherwise it doesn't), and I am trying to understand why. I thought Poincare-Hopf was the link, but now it doesn't seem like it. Any potentially relevant concepts?

Comment: I don't quite follow you. There is a differential topology version of the argument principle in complex analysis. If $f$ is a smooth map of the $n$-ball $B^n$ (or, more generally, a compact $n$-manifold with boundary) to $\Bbb R^n$ and $f\ne 0$ on $\partial B^n$, then the winding number of $f$ on the boundary around $0$ (i.e., the degree of the map $\frac{f}{|f|}\big|_{\partial B^n}\colon\partial B^n\to S^{n-1}$ is the sum of the local indices of $f$ at the zeroes inside $B^n$. (This is easiest to see if they are nondegenerate zeroes, and then you add up $\pm 1$'s.)

Comment: @TedShifrin, yes, that degree to the unit sphere was the Brouwer degree I was talking about for the map $f(x,y)$ (which I also called $h(x,y)$ by mistake). This degree is related to the Euler characteristic ($=\frac{1}{2}\chi$). However, I now have a second map $v(x,y)$ and the integral $\oint \frac{v'(x)}{v(x)}$, which by the argument principle in complex analysis gives the number of zeros inside the loop (with multiplicity); but this number seems to correspond to the degree of the first map.

Comment: I am trying to see why these two are related (degree of $f$ = multiplicity of zero from $v$). Is it more a problem of showing that the two maps are related, then? Note: In this case, it is a given that the only zero of $f$ occurs at a specific X-space point, and it is observed that the winding integral for $v$ gives the multiplicity of $f$ only if the loop encloses the specific point.